# Add a GridLayout to a GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, grouplayout

I am trying to add a `GridLayout` to a `GroupLayout` in my Java GUI.  I know that I can add components such as buttons, text boxes, panels, etc. to the `GroupLayout` by using `.addComponent('componentName')` but it does not work for adding a `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't add layouts to layouts, but rather components to containers. If you want to add "GridLayout" *behavior* to a GroupLayout using container, you'll need to create a JPanel that *uses* a GridLayout, and then add that JPanel to the GroupLayout-using container in a fashion as you've mentioned above.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I didn't know if there was a way to add the layout to the layout though. Thank you for your response :)